# Complex number with geometry.

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

**Question**

> [image]

**My attempt**

$ -\arg(z1/z2)=\arg(z1)-\arg(z2) $

$z1=(x+\alpha)+iy $ and  $ z2=(x+\beta)+iy $

$\arg(z1)=\arctan(y/x+\alpha) $ and $ \arg(z2)=\arctan(y/x+\beta) $ ....

But this method is very lengthy. Is there another elegant approach?

Comment: Actually,How to edit I don't know sorry .

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. To edit, click the [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4487835/edit) link (it should be the third one from the left side, between the "Cite" and "Follow" ones, just below your question).

Comment: May I have the source? Thx

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh look at the complex equation given. This represents an arc of a circle. I think you need to read up on it.

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh What is the role of $w$ given in the question?

Comment: Is $arg(z) =\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) $ always true?

Comment: @LostinSpace that’s for the sake of definition.

Comment: @insipidintegrator: Can you give me detailed solution and analysis of the problem for complete understanding.My method is very calculative and confusing .

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Circular_Arc_in_Complex_Plane and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102782/complex-number-locus-of-a-point. Read these and then update your post to include further efforts after reading the links.

Comment: @insipidintegrator:Can you refer me some books for Geometry of complex number ,Problem solving for Undergraduate level problems,Conic section.

Comment: Respected,@insipidintegrator:I understand the concept of the problem thanks a lot

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh see 1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717220/book-references-about-complex-geometry?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C87.8978 2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046810/book-recommendation-for-complex-numbers-and-co-ordinate-geometry 3. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768852/can-anyone-suggest-a-book-on-using-complex-numbers-to-solve-geometry-problems?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C81.2568